# set android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar images

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design

I am using  `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` with `ViewPager` like this :

```
 TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabanim_tabs);
 tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

the tab is displaying with **text** of the `ViewPager` when I add the dummy `Fragment` to it

```
 adapter.addFrag(new Fragment(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_light)), "XYZ");
```

i want the **image to display** instead of a text.

Comment: You wrote the question and answer at the same time. Then what was the purpose of the question if you already knew the answer?

Comment: @AritraRoy this platform is supposed to help people and i live by the same rule. I was looking the answer my self first but i couldn't find. Then i figure it out myself. I have posted this question and answer by myself to help people who came across the same problem. If anyone have better answer plz post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it by using this

```
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.brands);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText("");

    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.food);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText("");

    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.cinema);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setText("");
```